# How to login to gamecenter at PewDiePie's Tuber Simulator?

Tags: pewdiepie-tuber-simulator

How do I login to the Gamecenter on PewDiePie's Tuber Simulator, if you have not done it when they asked?

Comment: @RudolfL.Jelínek this was asked before

Answer (score 2):

Go into the settings app and find game center. Then it should prompt you to sign in to game center as it did with me. Once you do that open up tuber simulator and it should be fine