# How do I get my old account back?

Tags: pewdiepie-tuber-simulator

Can anyone tell me if there's a way to get my old account back please?
I clicked on "link account" and now for some reason it's made me start right at the beginning which is a shame cuz I really enjoyed playing this game. I've already logged in before but tended to click link account when it wouldn't go online which seemed to sort it out for some reason.
Thanks in advance

Comment: [Related?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/287034/how-to-login-to-gamecenter-at-pewdiepies-tuber-simulator?rq=1)

Comment: Still not working

Answer (score 1):

Just goto that friend option and there is Link Device option, tap on it and then goto New device and then select android if you have android phone or Other device if u have an IOS device. after that it will ask you, that all changes will be lost, you want to continue? Select yes.. ;)
Thank me later

If it's showing error, then there is no solution for that. I myself finding solution for that :/ i lost my lvl 16 account, **HardStone69**

If any of you guys have solution for that please let me know 
Instagram: cr_fardin 
Thanks, I came here looking for solution and here wanted to help you guys! ;)

Answer (score 1):

I also lost my account, I email them just now and they replied me less than 24 hours. You should not asking at here it's better to ask directly from developer.

This is the feedback from **OUTERMINDS** that they replied to me how to get back my account, hope it's going to help you.

> **-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**
>
> Hi,
>
> We’re
>    sorry you’ve been experiencing problems with our game, so here are some solutions that could help fix things.
>
> If
>    you linked your game with your Google Play or Game Center account, you can get it back in the social menu, just after you go through the short tutorial after you choose NEW GAME.  Be very careful not to set a new channel name as it will erase your old account.
>
> Click
>    on Link Account and follow the instructions by saying this is your NEW DEVICE.  Your account should now be able to connect to the online features as well.
>
> The
>    Link account/new device process specifically uses the last account made in either Google Play or the Game Center. If there was another account added afterwards, that will be the account used.
>
> Only
>    one account can be linked to Google Play or Game Center.
>   The
>    newest account overwrites the previous.
>
> If
>    no account is linked, there is no account to recover.
>
> Please
>    note that if you cheated and/or tried to change the date to progress faster, you will be brought back to the moment before the time change.
>
> Please
>    make sure you’ve updated to the latest version.
>   It
>    is very important to do so as any account not updated will not be able to connect online anymore.
>
> All
>    update info will be available on our official Twitter page.
>   https://twitter.com/outerminds
>
> **------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

Answer (score -1):

If youre playing on iOS unfortunately Apple have removed Game centre
, I'm having the same problem and had to contact the developer and Apple

Answer (score -3):

I don't think there's a way to fix it